# Joining two extra tables with two ON Conditions for both

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join, conditional-statements

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subscriberMaster.id,    
subscriberMaster.locationCodeID, subscriberMaster.firstName,
subscriberMaster.lastName, subscriberMaster.company, subscriberMaster.address,
subscriberMaster.address2, subscriberMaster.city, subscriberMaster.province,
subscriberMaster.postalCode, subscriberMaster.country,
subscriberMaster.numLabels
FROM subscriberMaster
JOIN commodityMaster ON commodityMaster.subscriberID = subscriberMaster.id AND
commodityMaster.commodityID IN (" . $commodityquery2 . ")
JOIN industryMaster ON industryMaster.subscriberID = subscriberMaster.id AND
industryMaster.industryID IN (" . $industryquery2 . ")
WHERE subscriberMaster.locationCodeID = $locationCodeID AND
subscriberMaster.province IN (" . $provincequery2 . ") AND
(subscriberMaster.deleted = 0) AND (subscriberMaster.expiryDate = '00-00-00')
OR (subscriberMaster.expiryDate > NOW()) ORDER BY $orderBy ASC");
```

Everything in this query was working just fine until I added a second join where it was also matching the same id from the main table. The Where clauses all works fine and the first join with both ON conditions worked. It seems to be an issue with the second JOIN clause.

Basically subscribersMaster is the main table with all the records details (address, phone number etc). CommodityMaster and IndustryMaster stores details on which industries they work in and what commodities they sell.

Here is what comes out when I echo the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT subscriberMaster.id, subscriberMaster.locationCodeID,
subscriberMaster.firstName, subscriberMaster.lastName, subscriberMaster.company,
subscriberMaster.address, subscriberMaster.address2, subscriberMaster.city,
subscriberMaster.province, subscriberMaster.postalCode, subscriberMaster.country,
subscriberMaster.numLabels FROM subscriberMaster
JOIN commodityMaster ON commodityMaster.subscriberID = subscriberMaster.id
JOIN industryMaster ON industryMaster.subscriberID = subscriberMaster.id
WHERE subscriberMaster.locationCodeID = 1 AND commodityMaster.commodityID IN ('1',
'2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19',
'20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33') AND
industryMaster.industryID IN ('1','3','2') subscriberMaster.province IN
('Ontario') AND (subscriberMaster.deleted = 0) AND (subscriberMaster.expiryDate =
 '00-00-00') OR (subscriberMaster.expiryDate > NOW())
ORDER BY company ASC
```

Comment: Please make an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), it makes it much easier for complex SQL questions.

Comment: I would but I just don't have the time at this moment. Deadline is coming up and can't seem to get this working.

Comment: Basically commodity and industry tables are same idea. In subscribersMaster you have all there details. Commodity has a list of 33 options that is stored in commodityMaster. Ever option they select creates a new record. So said there id is 550 and they selected 4 options in commodities, it records 4 records in the commodityMaster under the subscribeID column 550.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly does it mean `issue withs second clause`? Does the query give syntax or runtime errors ? If yes, please show error number and message. Or rather the query doesn't give desired results ? If yes, then describe what results do you get from the query, and what results are expected.